# UML class diagram for online reservations, need some assistance

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

For a school project I have to develop a website that handles booking-reservations for one vacation house. The idea is that the administrator can add customers to a CRM-system. Only then, customers can login with their chosen credentials.
When the customer makes a reservation, it is up to the administrator to give it a status, which can be: ACCEPTED, REJECTED or VALIDATING. The last one is the standard status for every reservation.

Here the updated class diagram:
[image]

While designing the UML class diagram, I found some errors.
Firstly, for the project we wanted to have a list, available for the administrator only, filled with all reservations. But also a list, per customer, just for ease.
Secondly, for the project a CRM-system. Which contains all data, reservations, customers, login credentials (hashed of course!)

Now, how do I imply that, to the class diagram?

Looking forward to your answers!

Firstly I tried to put all customers and reservations in 2 different ArrayLists, as seen in the attached image. But I wasn't sure how I could access them from the administrator perspective.

Comment: There's no attached image.  I'd recommend adding what you want to a CRM management class that allows different access based on roles for groups that contain users.  Get the API for the CRM right and worry about the access later.  UML and design doesn't care about implementation language.  I'd also get the object model right with a text UI.  You can add a GUI later when that's working.

Comment: @duffymo thank you! Makes way more sense! 
I’ve attached the image as we speak. If you’re able, could you have a quick look at it? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your UML diagram doesn't include a `ReservationSystem` class, you're doing it wrong.

Customer and Administrator should not own *any* lists.   The `ReservationSystem` does.  It should expose methods that allow different Roles to view, add, update, and remove instances of `Reservation`.  The private implementation might use Java `List`; it could choose to use any other collection to maintain instances of `Reservation` in memory OR a relational database to persist them.  The beauty is that users need not know or care how you choose to persist the data.

Customer and Administrator are just different Roles.  A Customer should only see their Reservations.  An Administrator should be able to see ALL of them.

Make your UML reflect these ideas if you agree.

Here's how I might do it:

[image]

Here is the [Plant UML](https://plantuml.com/) text file I created to generate it:

```
@startuml

!theme vibrant

title Reservation Class Diagram

    class Customer #LightBlue
    class Reservation #LightBlue

    class ReservationManager #LightBlue {
        reservationRepository
        findAll()
        findById()
        saveOrUpdate()
        remove()
    }

    class CustomerManager #LightBlue {
        customerRepository
        findAll()
        findById()
        saveOrUpdate()
        remove()
    }

    interface GenericRepository #LightBlue {
        findAll()
        findById()
        saveOrUpdate()
        remove()
    }
    interface ReservationRepository #LightBlue
    interface CustomerRepository #LightBlue


    class InMemoryReservationRepository #LightBlue
    class RelationalReservationRepository #LightBlue

    class InMemoryCustomerRepository #LightBlue
    class RelationalCustomerRepository #LightBlue

    enum Role #LightBlue {
        CUSTOMER
        ADMIN
    }

    ReservationManager *-- ReservationRepository : "has a"
    CustomerManager *-- CustomerRepository : "has a"

    ReservationManager -up-> Role : "uses"
    CustomerManager -up-> Role : "uses"

    Reservation "many" o-right- "1" ReservationRepository : "persists"
    Customer "many" o-left- "1" CustomerRepository : "persists"

    GenericRepository <|-left- ReservationRepository : "extends"
    GenericRepository <|-right- CustomerRepository : "extends"
    ReservationRepository <|-- InMemoryReservationRepository : "implements"
    ReservationRepository <|-- RelationalReservationRepository : "implements"
    CustomerRepository <|-- InMemoryCustomerRepository : "implements"
    CustomerRepository <|-- RelationalCustomerRepository : "implements"


@enduml
```

Comment: Just updated the image attached to this post. 
I think this is what you meant? Also, since databases aren't on any class diagrams, I left the CRM system out. But it might be wise to add a CustomerSystem class as well?

Comment: The important thing is how happy you are.  A Customer manager might be a fine idea.  The Reservation manage would have an instance of the Customer manager and allow Customers to register themselves.  This is a good spot for interfaces.  You hide your persistence details behind an interface.  You can switch from in-memory to relational database persistence just by injecting a new implementation of the interface.  It might be a good idea to add that to the diagram as well.

Comment: To be honest, UML is quite difficult, for me ;)
I uploaded a new version.
Not sure how to implement interfaces in this particular case...
The idea is that the administrator must create the customers, because not everyone is allowed make a reservation.

Comment: I did some research on how to implement a dataPersistence interface. I added the following operators:
saveCustomer()
loadCustomer()
deleteCustomer()
Should this be enough to also find the reservations per customer? By loading in the customer, with all of their reservations?

Comment: No worries - everything is difficult the first time.  Design is hard, even if you've tried to do it for a long time.  No way for customers to self-register?  Okay.  That's a design decision.   The Reservation and Customer management objects would each have their own interface.  You want CRUD operations for Reservation and Customer, respectively.

Comment: True! Takes long time to practice. 
So for both the customer and reservation systems, there should be an interface instead of a class?

Comment: You choose to use interfaces when you want to be able to change implementations without affecting clients.  I would make the Customer and Reservation admin classes, and give them interfaces to CustomerRepository and ReservationRepository.

Comment: @duffymoNot sure if I understand correctly, can you make an visual example?

Comment: I'll recommend that you look at Plant UML.  It lets you create class, sequence, and other UML diagrams with a text editor: https://plantuml.com/

Comment: No, sorry.  I'm not doing your homework for you.  Do your best based on what you understand.

Comment: Understandable! It ain't homework, it's a small thing of a big project. Totally respect that you won't do it. 
I'll try and figure it out according to the amazing help you provided.
Thank you very much for you answers and time.

Comment: It's my pleasure.  Feel free to ask again if you think it helps.

Comment: First of all, damn that design looks nice! I just have one question. What is the usage of the InMemoryRepository? Or was it meant as a choice, InMemory or RelationalRepository?

Comment: Meant as a choice.  I would use dependency injection to decide if I wanted an in-memory database that disappeared when the JVM exited or a relational database that would live on.  I use Java and Spring Boot.  Here's an old article by Martin Fowler about the idea behind dependency injection: https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: thanks will look into that, seems interesting!
As we speak I'm adding the attributes to the classes. 
I was also thinking of designing the database. Might save me a lot of time.